# App to track which person in the conversation has spoken the most

Tags: android, iphone, statistics

I got the idea of an app that could show you, after a telephone call, what percentage of the time you were speaking and what percentage of the time you're conversation partner was talking.

For this I had two conceptual approaches, and I was wondering which of the two was most suitable for this application.

- Voice recognition - During/after the call the app analyses the audio. Based on the amount of your voice present in the conversation it calculates a percentage
- Data recognition - I assume that when you talk the phone uploads more data then when you're silent. Based on the amount of kbps the talking distribution can be determined

Comment: A) you can't get access to the phone conversation data and B) if you could, Apple wouldn't allow this on the App Store (privacy restrictions)

Comment: I would be interested in this but for any audio recorded conversation, (to show someone they monopolize conversations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You couldn't get access to the phone conversation data itself, but you can get the up/download statistics. There are a few apps available that track 3g data by other apps (most phonecalls now a day use 3g). You could start tracking this when a phone call comes in, filter the other app datatraffic out, and then end when the phone call ends. This way you can know the amount of traffic being send in & out. You would have to do some basic testing beforehand, as there will lot's of overhead data being transmitted besides the voices themself. You could do some testing to see if there is a correlation (and by what extend) between the amount of talking and data traffic (there should be).